# Rest API Field Requirements

Tags: php, forms, rest, api

I'm curious to see if there is a solution to send Field Requirements (type, length, required) together with the API, which I can use for Form Validation.

So... What I expect, is the following:

- Page loads
- Gets required fields and their requirements from API.
- Builds form based on requirements

Comment: Just add more properties to the response body to specify the requirements

Comment: Got any proper example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Just add more properties to the response body to specify the requirements. For example:

```
{
    "fields": [{
        "field": "username",
        "type": "String",
        "minLength": 3,
        "maxLength": 20,
        "required": true
    }, {
        "field": "password",
        "type": "String",
        "minLength": 6,
        "maxLength": 15,
        "required": true
    }]
}
```